# How can I run a MVC-4 app in a Azure Worker Role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have seen in the link below that it is possible to have the long running WorkerRole main loop in a Azure Web Role.

http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2010/12/how-to-combine-worker-and-web-role-in.html

Is it possible to have an Azure WorkerRole that spawns the ASP.NET MVC-4 app from its main loop (RoleEntryPoint.Run()) method?

Does anyone have a pointer to a snippet that does this?

thanks,
rui

Comment: As far as I know, the worker roles do not have IIS installed (or maybe enabled), so achieving this probably won't work for hosting a site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tommy. I do suspect that might be the issue.

Comment: You don't NEED to use IIS to run a webserver. Try nancy or Owin.

Comment: @Aron - however, you would need to install that on the worker role AND you would need to ensure that your deployment package included the instructions and ability to install and configure if the worker role server ever moves within the data center (it happens, and is why one should not store long term files in the web/worker roles).  No one is saying your need IIS to host a website, but within an azure role, it is probably easiest just to use a web role.  The inclusion of IIS is about the only difference between the two.

Comment: @Tommy Agreed its not a good idea. Just that I believe its possible. Owin should allow you to self host. As should nancy self hosting.

Answer (score 1):

What is your scenario for wanting to do this?  Worker Roles do not have IIS installed, so you won't be able to run MVC4 in a worker role.  If you are just wanting to have a Run() method in an MVC4 webrole then you can add the following to WebRole.cs (much like the article you linked mentions).  This will cause the following code to run in the WaIISHost.exe process while your MVC4 code runs in w3wp.exe.

```
    public override void Run()
    {
        // Your code here
        base.Run();
    }
```